# How to Record a Video Call-in with Screen Share?

Tags: screen-sharing, conferencing

I need to enable someone to "call" me with video chat in a way that I can record their video, my video, and share a screen all at the same time (for vodcasting call-ins). I've tried using Zoom, but the moment I share my screen, it moves all the video off to the side and wrecks my recording ability/layout. I could use OBS to record if the video feed would stay put, but since it doesn't, I can't. Apart from keeping video in the right spot, I also need to be able to share a link but pick and choose who can come in (or at the very least keep it to one at a time). How can I go about this?

Comment: What about using separate tools for conferencing & recording?

Comment: OBS is what I would like to use for recording, but the conferencing isn't consistent with where faces are and how big they are (at least with Zoom). And if I'm having people call in for video chat, I would certainly prefer that the screen-sharing app is the same so they don't have to call into two different places.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sharing through zoom or even another app, I can use OBS to output a virtual camera of whatever I have recording currently. The other person in Zoom will then see this virtual cam with whatever I am streaming. This enables me to swap between views in OBS and thus also in Zoom so the other person can see "just me" or "the two of us" or "the two with shared screen". It seems to work fairly well.